# What are ways to run a script only after another script has finished?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, callback

Lets say this is my code (just a sample I wrote up to show the idea)

```
var extract = require("./postextract.js");
var rescore = require("./standardaddress.js");

RunFunc();

function RunFunc() {
    extract.Start();
    console.log("Extraction complete");
    rescore.Start();
    console.log("Scoring complete");
}
```

And I want to not let the rescore.Start() run until the entire extract.Start() has finished. Both scripts contain a spiderweb of functions inside of them, so having a callback put directly into the Start() function is not appearing viable as the final function won't return it, and I am having a lot of trouble understanding how to use Promises. What are ways I can make this work?

These are the scripts that extract.Start() begins and ends with. OpenWriter() is gotten to through multiple other functions and streams, with the actual fileWrite.write() being in another script that's attached to this (although not needed to detect the end of run. Currently, fileWrite.on('finish') is where I want the script to be determined as done

```
module.exports = {
  Start: function CodeFileRead() {
    //this.country = countryIn;
    //Read stream of thate address components
    fs.createReadStream("Reference\\" + postValid.country + " ADDRESS REF DATA.csv")
      //Change separator based on file
      .pipe(csv({escape: null, headers: false, separator: delim}))
      //Indicate start of reading
      .on('resume', (data) => console.log("Reading complete postal code file..."))
      //Processes lines of data into storage array for comparison
      .on('data', (data) => {
        postValid.addProper[data[1]] = JSON.stringify(Object.values(data)).replace(/"/g, '').split(',').join('*');
        })
      //End of reading file
      .on('end', () => {
        postValid.complete = true;
        console.log("Done reading");
        //Launch main script, delayed to here in order to not read ahead of this stream
        ThisFunc();
      });
  },

  extractDone
}

function OpenWriter() {
    //File stream for writing the processed chunks into a new file
    fileWrite = fs.createWriteStream("Processed\\" + fileName.split('.')[0] + "_processed." + fileName.split('.')[1]);
    fileWrite.on('open', () => console.log("File write is open"));
    fileWrite.on('finish', () => {
      console.log("File write is closed");
    });
}
```

EDIT: I do not want to simply add the next script onto the end of the previous one and forego the master file, as I don't know how long it will be and its supposed to be designed to be capable of taking additional scripts past our development period. I cannot just use a package as it stands because approval time in the company takes up to two weeks and I need this more immediately

DOUBLE EDIT: This is all my code, every script and function is all written by me, so I can make the scripts being called do what's needed

Comment: Does `extract.Start()` return a promise?

Comment: How would I make it do that? I wrote them so its whatever I want it to return, I'm just not sure where or how

Comment: You have to post a simple minimal complete verifiable example of the code for `extract.Start()` and `rescore.Start();`

Comment: Added it into the post, it shows the first and last scripts, both function the same (starting with a read stream and ending with a write stream)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just wrap your function in Promise and return that.

```
module.exports = {
  Start: function CodeFileRead() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.createReadStream(
        'Reference\\' + postValid.country + ' ADDRESS REF DATA.csv'
      )
      // .......some code...
      .on('end', () => {
        postValid.complete = true;
        console.log('Done reading');
        resolve('success');
      });
    });
  }
};
```

And Run the RunFunc like this:

```
async function RunFunc() {
  await extract.Start();
  console.log("Extraction complete");
  await rescore.Start();
  console.log("Scoring complete");
}

//or IIFE
RunFunc().then(()=>{
  console.log("All Complete");
})
```

Note: Also you can/should handle error by `reject("some error")` when some error occurs.

**EDIT After knowing about TheFunc():**

Making a new Event emitter will probably the easiest solution:
eventEmitter.js

```
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter
module.exports = new EventEmitter()
```

```
const eventEmitter = require('./eventEmitter');
module.exports = {
  Start: function CodeFileRead() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      //after all of your code
      eventEmitter.once('WORK_DONE', ()=>{
        resolve("Done");
      })
    });
  }
};
function OpenWriter() {
  ...
  fileWrite.on('finish', () => {
    console.log("File write is closed");
    eventEmitter.emit("WORK_DONE");
  });
}
```

And Run the RunFunc like as before.

Comment: This ends up running them together and not waiting for the entire script to finish

Comment: So the `ThisFunc` also asynchronous function? I thought that was a dummy.

Comment: That calls the next function in the chain of functions for that script. The chain eventually ends with OpenWriter being called

Comment: Its not asynchronous, its just used because we need to load the entire file into memory before beginning the process that works through all the data

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: What is your address so I can kiss you. I've been dealing with this kind of issue since I started the project, you are amazing, thank you. This worked perfectly. I just need to figure out how to pass the event emitter between scripts now and you will have solved so much, thank you

Comment: Thanks. Just require the same `eventEmitter.js` and it will be available in all the scripts.

Comment: This will be helpful for my home automation system as well, because I needed a way to detect when the hue lights are changed and so using the event emitter is a god send

Answer (score 1):

There's no generic way to determine when everything a function call does has finished.

It might accept a callback. It might return a promise. It might not provide any kind of method to determine when it is done. It might have side effects that you could monitor by polling.

You need to read the documentation and/or source code for that particular function.

Comment: They are my functions, I wrote the entirety of this code, so I can have them return or do what's needed

Comment: @TheBasementNerd — We don't know what they do. I suggested three things that could be used to determine when asynchronous code is finished in this answer (although polling side effects is *awful*). Pick one of them and make the function do that.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd put these into that aside from callback, but as it calls one function in the script and the script ends with another, without passing a callback through every single function I didn't see that as viable. Or does it sound like that might have to be the way?

Answer (score 1):

Use async/await (promises), example:

```js
var extract = require("./postextract.js");
var rescore = require("./standardaddress.js");
RunFunc();

async function extract_start() {
   try {
       extract.Start()
   }
   catch(e){
      console.log(e)
   }
}

async function rescore_start() {
   try {
       rescore.Start()
   }
   catch(e){
      console.log(e)
   }
}

async function RunFunc() {
    await extract_start();
    console.log("Extraction complete");
    await rescore_start();
    console.log("Scoring complete");
}
```

Comment: This ends up just running extract.Start() and then the program finishes, and that appears to be the issue with most of the times I try to do a promise system, or do I need to put something into the extract and rescore script?